# Broken raspberry pi 4 case python3 script causes disk errors

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kali-linux, python3

I am using kali linux on raspberry pi 4 and argon one case

I installed argon one fan and power button script with that command:

```
sudo curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/meuter/argon-one-case-ubuntu-20.04/master/argon1.sh  |bash
```

[Whole script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/meuter/argon-one-case-ubuntu-20.04/master/argon1.sh)

Fan works perfectly after enabling module but when I try to use button, next boot system will scan disk 1 on every boot, I tried removing dirty bit but it did nothing.

I reinstalled kali linux and tried to modify shutdown script from python to
`#!/bin/bash`
`wall test`

And after restarting deamon and pressing button it didn't turn off and walled test in terminal but after reboot same thing happens

Comment: Disk is SD card with FAT filesystem?

Comment: boot partition is fat32

Comment: second partition is ext4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by code of Argon installer you can see that it puts its code in "shutdown event" (/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/), which according to systemd [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-halt.service.html) will

> Before shutting down ... unmount all remaining file systems ... detach all remaining storage

then

> Immediately before executing the actual system halt/poweroff/reboot/kexec systemd-shutdown will run all executables in /usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/

(by reading them from filesystem reattached as readonly)

However it appears that in your case filesystem is still read-write instead of readonly when power supply is turned off (with `bus.write_byte(0x1a,0xFF)`). Offhand I'd guess that its caused by differences between Linux distribution/configuration.

You should be able to confirm whether or not your Argon device, and its scripts, work correctly by testing it on Raspberian (which it appears to be tested on). Or you could try to modify poweroff script to check if file system actually is read-only.
However it might also be prudent to just double-check if your SD card is actually in working condition, as those devices have their own set of potential issues.

Comment: So if I just remove line bus.write_byte(0x1a,0xFF) will it work? I don't need that forced shutdown if I understand correctly?

Comment: When I use original script on raspbian it works flawlessly

Comment: Omg thank you, after I just removed execution from this file it just works, I really don't know what it was doing, can you explain it on surface level?

Comment: And it's broken again, after I press button for too long it's forcing shutdown

Comment: @Gyanbu "bus.write" sends a poweroff command to Argon Hat, thats why it must be sent when system is ready for poweroff. (eg. to not damage filesystem)
As for power button itself, it has multiple behaviors. Check "powerbuttonscript" content. Holding it for 2-3 seconds will cause soft reboot, 4-5 will cause soft shutdown, and 5+ will be hard shutdown (same as forcing shutdown on PC, bypassing OS and going directly via power supply). Soft shutdown is same as just clicking it in start menu, which will call power-off script.

Comment: @Gyanbu actual problem you have is something like "system-shutdown script is called before filesystem is remounted as readonly in Kali", which I have no idea how to fix so you'd better ask on https://unix.stackexchange.com/  :)

Comment: Thanks i will just replace shutdown now -h to shutdown now, becouse i think that's it @PTwr

Comment: Can you write me all places that are hard shutting down my pi? Thanks

Comment: Nice, deleting -h argument worked